# How to JOIN Multiple Tables in an SQL Database in Order to Get Product IDs, OrderIDs, and the Customer info all in One Table?

Tags: sql, database, left-join, inner-join

I'm not new to SQL coding, I'm just typically used to doing small data requests in PHP from the database but every now and then am faced with an issue to where I need to join tables and it's just way over my head. I decided I would start expanding my knowledge in that area by trying to accomplish one single task, but am totally stumped.

I'm learning this from W3Schools Website so all my referencing is from the DATABASE in their TryItEditor located here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

I'm trying to use SQL to display the **CustomerName** with the **OrderID** they placed, as well as the **ProductName** and **ProductID**.

The way I was trying to do this-- which I know is probably wrong, but I'm new to this-- was to use a **LEFT JOIN** or **INNER JOIN** to first JOIN the the two columns **Products.ProductID** and **OrderDetails.ProductID**. Then I was trying to JOIN **OrderDetails.ProductID** as well. Then finally, trying to JOIN **Customers.CustomerID** to **Orders.CustomerID**.

Here is my Code:

`SELECT Products.ProductID, OrderDetails.ProductID, Products.ProductName, Customers.CustomerName, Products.ProductName, Orders.OrderID FROM  OrderDetails LEFT JOIN Products ON  OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID LEFT JOIN Orders ON  OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID LEFT JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;`

However when I ran this code, it is displaying `101528` rows though I clearly know according to the **Orders** table that there has only been a total of 196 Orders.

I've tried going through various tutorials I found online to understand how to do this, but I'm not getting the result I desire. If someone could point me in the right direction what I'm trying to do, It would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
My desired output is to see 196 Rows (Number of Orders) with the following Columns:

**Product ID -- ProductName -- CustomerName -- OrderID --**

UPDATE to Nathans Answer:

`SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Orders.OrderID, Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName, Customers.CustomerName FROM Orders INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID`

I was able to get the desired view, but still too many rows.

Comment: Your resultset will have the same number of rows as the OrderDetails table - which I assume will be much greater than the number of Orders as each Order will have many corresponding OrderDetail records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with inner joins. Left join means you show the row on the left even if the row on the right isn’t there. Time for left joins after you can do inner joins.

It helps to have an ERD. If you don’t have one already, draw one. Pick a starting table that looks like a good place to get all the information you need. The joins follow the relationships in the diagram.

I would first join order to order detail using order Id.
Then join order detail to product using product Id.
Then join order to customer by customer Id.

Add the joins one at a time and confirm the results make sense.  Notice that if you join orders to order details by order Id,  you are going to get back a number of rows equal to the number of details, not the number of orders.

Comment: @JCBiggar: you joined order details to product, then product to order.

Comment: So I updated my question to post the code I tried... That worked to display my desired view, but there are still too many rows. There should only be 196 orders total. Please correct me where I went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @JCBiggar: you saw where NickW and I both pointed out that the query should return a number of rows equal to the details, not the number of orders?

Comment: Yes! and its just now hitting me. Making a little more sense now. How would I go about getting just the number of rows from Orders? Is that even possible?

Comment: @JCBiggar: you can leave out the detail table, you lose products though. You may want to draw an ERD to help picture this.

Comment: Make sense! Well that helped alot! Thanks Nathan!